# How to prove that a cone is closed?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

How to prove a cone $K$ is closed? By showing that its complement is open?

Comment: How exactly is your cone defined? What you give here is a bit too rough of a definition to work with. Also, note that there are sets which are neither open nor cosed - in fact, there are some that are both. What you probably mean, however, is that a set is open if and only if its complement is closed.

Comment: Not all cones are closed.

Comment: Hi, My definition of cone is as follows: A nonempty set $C$ is called a cone if and only if it is closed under positive scalar multiplication. Can anyone give me an example to show that a cone is closed ?

Comment: @guanglei, please read my answer and apply it to $X - \{0\}$

Comment: "if it is not open, then it is closed" This statement is not correct.  For example, the interval $[0,1)$ is neither open or closed.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is false.

For example, the set $$X = \{0\} \cup \{  t_1x + t_2x_2 : t_1,t_2 >0, x_1 \neq x_2 \}$$

is a cone, but if we select $y_n = \frac{1}{n}x_1 + x_2$ then notice $\lim y_n = x_2 \notin X$. The situation can be reformuated with $X - \{ 0 \}$ depending on your definition of a cone.